# How to scroll uiwebview to page only

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using IOS7 new feature of `UIWebView` to create pagination of HTML page.

Here is the code.

```
self.webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
self.webView.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
```

Now the HTML page is divided into pages that fit the `UIWebView`. However, there are a couple of issues.

1) When I swipe my finger from left to right, it should swipe to the next page (exactly page). Now when I swipe, it can stop between two pages. I want to stop at the page only, not between the pages.

2) Is it possible to get the current page number? I know there is a property called `pageCount` can give you the total page number. But I did not find how to get the current page number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the asker found, you can solve (1) by setting `pagingEnabled` on the scroll view.

Since iOS 5, `UIWebView` has a [`scrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scrollView) property to access its scroll view. No need to check look through the `subviews` checking `[UIScrollview class]` anymore.

You can solve (2) by looking at the scroll view’s `contentOffset` and `contentSize` and calculating the current page from that.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy by using the following setting.

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set UIWebview's scrollview's pagingEnabled property to YES in after your webview is  loaded:

```
    UIScrollView* scrollView = nil;
    for (UIView *subView in [self.pageWebview subviews]) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            scrollView = (UIScrollView*)subView;
            scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
```